# Intellij Debugging - Why is step in/step out greyed out?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-14

This is what I see in my Intellij UI IDE

[image]

The correct breakpoint is being hit(line 128 - checkRunFlag() )

but the step over/step in buttons next to console in the bottom left part of the screen are greyed out. Does anyone know what is causing this/how I can re-enable those buttons?

Comment: You probably lost the focus on the line or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was greyed out until i entered a input (i.e part of program before breakpoint). After i entered the input using Scanner class, i was able to access step into and other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

change to  your debug application

Comment: I tried clicking that but didn't see any additional options. I think I'm already in debug application mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what the cause of this issue was but what I did to fix the issue was call kill -9 with the process id of Intellij

Then I restarted Intellij and it's working fine now

Answer (score 0):

you can click the "pause pragram"  to see where the breakpoints stopped. then make sure it's your expect application.
[image]